# CMake-qt: Including Autogened file from sibling Project. How to do it right?

Tags: qt, cmake

commonLib is a collection of Files used for some other Targets declared in sibling folders which are then added to the parent CMakeLists.txt via add_subdirectory(). commonLib contains foo.h and foo.ui (which is translated to ui_foo.h by AUTOUIC)

otherLib includes foo.h from commonLib.

It feels like I am missing something obvious.

Is it necessary to use something like target_link_libraries?
Can I add the autogen folder of commonLib to the include folders of otherLib? (with target_include_directories(commonLib PRIVATE ${AUTOGEN_FOLDER_OF_otherLib}) )

How do I make sure commonLib is autogen-ed before otherLib?

Please let me know if there is information missing for understanding the problem.

I am using cmake-converter to convert existing .sln files to CMakeLists.txt.

I assumed finding success with using target properties like:
* AUTOGEN_TARGET_DEPENDS
* AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR

but I failed.

commonLib contains following code:

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    AUTOUIC ON
)
```

otherLib contains following code:

```
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}
    commonLib
)
```

I expected CMake to successfully generate the ui_foo.h from commonLib (which it actually does in the folder commonLib_autogen/include_) and then use ui_foo.h for compilation with otherLib.

Resulting Errormessage is:

```
d:\path\to\otherLib\../otherLib/foo.h(6): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ui_foo.h': No such file or directory [D:\build_dir_of\otherLib\otherLib.vcxproj]
```

Comment: I just found a way how it worked, but I am pretty sure it's not a best practice approach:

In ProjectB adding 
```cmake
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../projectA/foo.h
```
to the sources resulted in compilation without errors. Is there a better approach?

Comment: CMake can adjust dependencies neither between *projects* nor between *directories*. Only **targets** and **files** can be part of dependencies graph. Assuming `ProjectA` to be a some **target**, which depends on `ui_foo.h` **file**, building that target would create that file, and `add_dependencies(ProjectB ProjectA)` would enforce existing of the file when the target `ProjectB` is built. Specifying `add_executable(ProjectB <sources> <path/to/ui_foo.h>)` should also work.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain this to me! :)
I will adjust the Naming to avoid misconceptions. Project* are subfolders added to a CMakeLists.txt in the parent folder. They are Targets on their own. But my mistake was at a totally different point. I **missed activating** AUTOMOC for the depending target, which seemed to be necessary for ui_foo.h being generated (from the first target) when building the depending target. Lesson learned: Use the vocabulary/keywords more precisely, avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was the use of

`# include "ui_foo.h"`

in the header (foo.h). Moving the include to the foo.cpp file and forward declaring the `Ui::FooBar` like this:

`namespace Ui { class FooBar; }`

resolved it.